# get meta fields and taxonomy of any post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-meta

I have created 6 different custom post type, each having different post meta and taxonomies associated with it.
I am displaying all different custom post types in a dropdown using  `get_post_types()` function,
Now, onchange of dropdown, I want to display associated meta fields and taxonomy.

I know that this information is not saved in DB unless a post is created, so
is it possible to read this information like WordPress is reading or
please suggest me if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to get the taxonomies associated with a custom post type object, not with a specific single post. To do that you can use [get_object_taxonomies()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies). For example, to get the names of the associated taxonomies to "my-custom-post-type":

```
 $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'my-custom-post-type', 'names' );

 foreach( $taxonomies as $taxname ) {
     echo $taxname;
 }
```

I think you can not do the same for meta fields because meta fields are associated with a specific single post not with a post type object. You will have to hardcode the relationship between metafields and custom post type.

Comment: yes, I got it for taxonomies but I need it for the post_meta also. After lots of searching, I am also started to think that it is not possible.Thanks for your help.